# Is it possible to add a mercurial or git extension inside a repository?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-extensions, mercurial-extension

If the question is not clear enough, I will try to explain it:

I am wondering if you can add the extension code/script to your repository and enable it inside `.hg/hgrc` with a relative path.

If possible, this should enable you to distribute extensions with the repositories, as long the extension "code" can run on each platform.

Some, question applies for `git`.

Answer (score 1):

With Mercurial, you can add the extension code to the repository without a problem and you can also reference this same extension with a relative path.

However, and this is a deal breaker I think, you cannot enforce the activation of the extension upon the clone. Each user will have to setup manually the extension in his `hgrc`.

Comment: *"Each user will have to setup manually the extension in his hgrc"* - [projrc extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProjrcExtension) (now - part of TortoiseHG) solves this problem. But mentioned by Mark show-stopper still exist

Answer (score 0):

I've found that distributing an extension in the repository is fine, but the users should install it outside the repository.  The reason for this is that if a newer version of the extension is released, updating to older history downgrades the extension.  @krtek is right, the user has to enable the extension manually in .hg/hgrc as well.